# Как научить WebView открывать Input File — Менеджер файлов (выбор фото) для загрузки на сайт?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Раздаю разрешения приложению в манифесте на (Интернет/Камеру и Хранилище):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Размечаю все приложение в WebView в Activity Main

```
  <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

И сам Java КОД:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://dodating.ru");

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7d41f9"));

    myWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

}

Все работает отлично, за исключением выбора файла, он просто не вызывает меню выбора файла..

[image]

Как научить его обрабатывать кнопку вызова файла, как на рисунке ниже ?

[image]

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: вроде нужно передать intent с соответствующим данными, чтобы появилось окно, в котором будут все приложения, которые могут работать с этим типом данных

Comment: Вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907

Answer (score 1):

Задача состоит из 2-х частей:

1. Перехватить клик на кнопку в `WebView` - [пример смотрим здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview)
2. В перехвате инициировать просмотр/выбор из файловой системы. Здесь все еще проще. Если версия Android >=6.0 то тупо вызываем `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, указывая нужный `mimetype`, если версия Android KitKat и ниже - то будет чуток сложнее. Например [смотрим сюда](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)